# Simple blog post function

Tags: php, mysql

How would I create a simple blog posting function in PHP? I have a mySQL database with the following...

Table bloggers:
id, name

Table posts:
blogger id, post, timestamp

In plain English I want to display all posts with the blogger's name (by matching the id with blogger id) and a timestamp, and the posts ordered by the timestamp to have the most recent ones first.

My current endeavours of selecting each one nested within the other isn't working and I think I need to rethink the whole approach.

Comment: Seems like a trivial task, what have you done until now, may be you are thinking too complicated

Comment: The task is not really a blog post, I've simplified it because what I'm working on uses the same principle. Think of it as a sort of simple feed.

Comment: you do seem to be missing a post_id, and possibly a parent_post_id for the indenting of replys

Comment: Sorry, I do have a post id too.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you read up on the basics of SQL as this seems pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT 
   b.name, p.post, p.timestamp
FROM
   posts p
INNER JOIN
   bloggers b
ON 
   p.blogger_id = b.id
WHERE
   b.blogger_id = :id
ORDER BY
   p.timestamp DESC
```

Note that the `:id` part above is for use in a prepared statement, described below.

As for the PHP function, you should use [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) for this.

Answer (score 0):

try sql:

```
select * from bloggers A, posts B WHERE A.bloggerid = B.bloggerid
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not quite understand how you're organizing things but...

Assuming you can get the author's id by selecting the bloggers table and getting the id you want you could do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE blogger_id='" . $author_id . "' ORDER BY timestamp DESC") or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
 echo '<div class="post"><div class="time">' . $row['timestamp'] . '</div><div class="content">'. $row['post'] .'</div></div>';
}
```